# How get url with parameters from original request?

Tags: swift

I am trying to cancel a request from so many, but they all have the same url, what changes are the parameters, is there any way to distinguish them?

```
   let url: URL = URL(string: url)!
    let sessionManager = self.alamoSession
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
        for task in downloadTasks {
            if task.originalRequest?.url == url {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are actually two ways to distinguish what task this is.

First, when you created the task, it was assigned a unique `taskIdentifier`. You can maintain that information and use it to (get this) identify the task later.

Second, when you created the task, you had the opportunity to assign it a `taskDescription`. Again, you can maintain that information and use it to distinguish one task from another.